# Huge disk space usage but I can't find what

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-space

My Mac's disk is almost full. I've tried to delete files and checked out my /var/log but can't find any 'big' files.

What can I do to clean up my Macbook's disk space or to find out what is so huge?

[image]

Comment: Overig translates to "Remaining," correct?  So, does that mean that's how much space is available?  Or does Overig translate closer to "Other"?

Comment: I've translated the Dutch bits of the image into English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two GUI applications for Mac that help visually identify what's taking up disk space: [Disk Inventory X](http://www.derlien.com/) and [GrandPerspective](http://grandperspectiv.sourceforge.net/). If you've ever used [KDirStat](http://kdirstat.sourceforge.net/) or [WinDirStat](http://windirstat.sourceforge.net/) then you should be comfortable with it, but even if not it's fairly self-explanatory when you run it.

You can also [search by file size in Finder](http://osxdaily.com/2012/04/17/find-large-files-in-mac-os-x-search/).

[image: search by file size in Finder]

Answer (score 1):

Open terminal, run `du -s *` which lists the total size of all files in each directory.

```
cd /  # or cd to where you wish to check for large files    
du -s * | sort -nr | more
```

Pick large directories to run find on. this `find` command will list files exceeding 100,000,000 bytes; you can adjust the actual size specified to suit.

```
# list files with dir directory which are over 100,000,000 bytes
find dir -size +100000000c -ls
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [GrandPerspective](http://grandperspectiv.sourceforge.net/). It will show you a map of your files and directories depending on their size, so you can easily guess the location of your big files or directories:

[image: GrandPerspective]

Answer (score 0):

You can download and run a program called CCleaner.  It removes all those tiny nasty bug files that build up over time.  I try to run it weekly.  A mac version is available [here](http://www.piriform.com/blog/2012/12/21/ccleaner-for-mac-v106).